# Записать числа из файла в массив

Tags: c++

Есть функция которая открывает и читает файл. В файле числа записаны построчно.
Можно ли реализовать в цикле считывания строк их последующую запись в динамический массив?

```
int readFromTxt()
{
    string  line;
    int     counter     = 0;
    int     numStr      = 0;
    int*    inputData = new int;
    char*   fileName    = new char[128];
    fileName = "test.txt";

    ifstream readFile;
             readFile.open(fileName, ios_base::out);

                if (!readFile.is_open())
                    cout << "ERROR!" << fileName << "isnt open!" << endl;
                else

                while (getline(readFile,line))
                {
                    ++numStr;
                }
             readFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно, реализовывайте.

Comment: Я не понимаю как.

Comment: Есть славная функция atoi(), например.

Comment: только вот `int*    inputData = new int;` выделит памяти ровно под одно целое число. Либо выделяйте столько, чтобы наверняка хватило, либо используйте `std::vector<int>`, это будет действительно динамический массив (ну, почти массив)

Comment: @andy за подсказку спасибо.

Comment: А Вы пытались гуглить?

Comment: По запросу "записать числа из файла в массив" первые 5 ссылок дают примеры именно того, что Вам нужно. Зачем из этого ресурса делать помойку с домашними заданиями?

Comment: Мне честно говоря был бы полезен и намёк на использование вектора. Но я благодарен и за пример реализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> inputData;
    std::string line;
    int counter = 0;
    char filename[] = "test.txt";
    std::ifstream readfile;
    readfile.open(filename, std::ios_base::in);
    if (!readfile.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "cant open file" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    while (std::getline(readfile, line)) {
        counter++;
        int temp = std::stoi(line);
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        inputData.push_back(temp);
    }
    std::cout << inputData.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Тут, конечно, никакой обработки ошибок, типа некорректных строк, пустых строк в конце и т.п., но работает.

Comment: Не лишним будет заметить, что такая реализация подразумевает, что числа строго в рамках int. Еcли вам нужен другой формат, то замените <int> и функцию std::stoi. <long> -> stol, <long long> -> stoll, <float> -> stof, <double> -> stod, <long double> -> stold.

Comment: @ИльдарАхметов, да Вы правы. Более того, программа просто вылетит на неправильной строке. Ну и `stoi` в `std` начиная с 11-ого стандарта.

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Сегодня же возьмусь за реализацию.

Comment: @andy.37 
А что если в файле строки содержат белее одного слова и разделены табуляцией?
Уже пол дня курю форумы не могу понять. 'getline' ,thtn wtke. строку из файла?

Comment: @Ximerik, я вроде явно написал, что мой код подразумевает что все строки файла прядтавляют собой целые числа. Я не понимаю, что такое "целое число с пробелами и табуляциями". Для строк с пробелами есть ф-я `std::getline`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Comment: @andy вопрос уже снялся.